# Why `"%,2,%" like ",1,2,3,"` return zero?

Tags: mysql, singlestore

I got a SQL not working as expected. And I found out it's because of one of the like clause.

I expected the following sql

```
select * from SomeTable Where "%,2,%" like ",1,2,3,";
```

gives the same result as

```
select * from SomeTable;
```

but it actually gives nothing. 
I can't expand `",1,2,3,"` and I can't use `find_in_set` because I'm using memsql.
So is there any other way I can do to determine an entry is in a comma separated list string, or did i do anything wrong?

Comment: You didn't mean `select * from SomeTable Where "%,2,%" like ",1,2,3,";` did you?  The & must be on the right of the like: `select * from SomeTable Where ",1,2,3," like "%,2,%";`

Comment: Because you got it back to front. The match-pattern with the `%` characters in it goes after `LIKE`, and the value to compare goes before.

Comment: The best way to do this in MemSQL is via JSON.  Even if your data is not formated as JSON you could do something like:

json_array_contains_double(concat('[',column_with_list_of_ids,']'), 2) to get the same behavior as find_in_set(2, column_with_list_of_ids).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually meant that

```
select * from SomeTable Where ",1,2,3," LIKE "%,2,%" ;
```

Gives the same result as `SELECT * SomeTable.` Because  ",1,2,3," like "%,2,%" always evaluates to TRUE so. The above statement is indeed the same as

```
select * from SomeTable;
```

On the other hand in the following statement

```
select * from SomeTable Where "%,2,%" like ",1,2,3,";
```

The "%,2,%" like ",1,2,3," component always evaluates to False. This will give you zero results.

I think what you are really looking for is:

```
 select * from v Where somecolumn like "%,2,%"
```

Comment: "%,2,%" like ",1,2,3," === false ;

Comment: ",1,2,3," like "%,2,%"  === true

Comment: yes @SIDU, I was confused myself by the wording of the question. Changed now